# Why Underclocking gives better FPS than overclocking a graphics card?

Tags: performance, gpu, fps, underclock

I am playing a slightly intensive title called Far Cry 4 with a GT 710 I noticed that the game stutters a lot when I use +424Mhz for the core clock and +315Mhz for the memory clock.

When I reduce both values to +368Mhz and +308Mhz respectively then the stutter disappears and the game runs smoother.

So how does underclocking stabilize a game is all I want to understand, I thought this job was meant for overclocking but it looks like am wrong.

Comment: What utility do you use when overclocking?

Comment: `MSI AfterBurner`

Comment: Not every GPU can run faster than it is designed to.  Just because you are can overclock a GPU doesnt mean the GPU is capable.  If a GPU was able to reliably work at a higher speed, dont you think the manufacturer would sell it that way?

Comment: @Keltari, the initial overclock is still within the legal parameters permitted by the manufacturer

Comment: Please can you stop abusing the code formatting tool. Nothing in your question actually needs it and it is not supposed to be a general highlighting tool.

Comment: @Mokubai, point taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt underclock, you lowered the overclock.

Notice your values have a + in front of them, so they are Base Clock +Overclock. For example, your GPU was 954Mhz base + 424Mhz overclock = 1378Mhz. You now changed it to 954+368 = 1322Mhz. So you lowered your overclock by 56Mhz. Same happened with memory. Your original overclock is possibly to agressive, making the card too hot and throttle, lowering performance. By slightly lowering it, this problem went away.

Comment: so an underclock is basically a minus of the base frequency?

Comment: Everyone knows am right, because of the game far cry 5, when you disable hyperthreading in the bios for the cpu the fps is stable and doesn't go below 60

Comment: Yes, underclocking is lowering the BASE clock. So if base is 954Mhz, anything below is an underclock. Underclocking is ususally done to also undervolt, making the CPU/GPU require less power to keep it cooler or just to save on power.